# Revolutions per second?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In grinding certain tools the linear velocity of the the grinding surface should not exceed 6000 ft/s. Find the maximum number of revolution of a 12 inch diameter wheel?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you understand the relationship between angular velocity and linear velocity?

Answer (score 1):

This involves precisely the same notions as your other recent questions. The circumference of the grinding wheel (in feet) is $\pi$. So if the thing is going at $r$ revolutions per second, the linear speed of  the outer part of the grinding surface is $\pi r$ feet per second. This speed should be $\le 6000$ feet per second. So the largest allowed $r$ is the one for which $\pi r=6000$. Now solve for $r$.

By the way, $6000$ feet per second seems *awfully* fast!

Comment: That's a little under three times the muzzle velocity of an AK-47, and about $16\%$ of the Earth's escape velocity ...